# Overriding Zoom shortcut (control + / control -) does not work in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, overriding, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to override the Zoom shortcuts in Internet Explorer 9. Using jquery, I have an event handler that handles the keydown event on the document like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event)
                    {
                       event.preventDefault();
                    });
```

This should disable all shortcuts in the browser and works on most browsers (for the shortcuts I've tried). Shortcuts like ctrl-s are disabled, even in Internet Explorer 9. But the zoom (ctrl + / ctrl -) of Internet Explorer 9 keeps working. Is there any way to disable this shortcut? I thought that IE9 implemented the more standard way of handling shortcuts instead of using event.returnValue and window.event which you had to do in older IE versions.

PS. I know disabling all shortcuts has certain implications on the user's experience. But let's assume that it doesn't really matter in this particular case.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: @eXaminator Unfortunately no, I did not find a solution.